# How to upload an app via a team admin -app store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode7

I am a member of a iOS team of my client. My client has made me as admin in member center. I can now able to create certificates and provisional profiles.

Now, I have an app which needs to be uploaded into the App Store. As **I have admin rights in member center**, can I be able to upload apps on his behalf?

I tried to validate a build, but it says **No accounts with iTunes Connect access**. When I checked in xcode-preferences it is showing my account as agent, and my client's team as admin.

If am missing anything please let me know.

I have these questions

1. If I'm the admin, do I have rights to upload a build to app store?
2. If not, can a agent upload apps to app store?
3. Can my client make me as the agent.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Krishna need to give full right by admin then and then you can able to upload the build to appstore.

Answer (score -1):

You probably have a Admin account in [iTunesAccount](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/users_roles), but not in the [member center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#adpDev). The iTunesConnect have 5 roles like technical, finance, sales... But the member center has only three roles **agent** (only one), **admin**, **technical**.

Only the users with the admin role in the member center can submit apps.

Check if you have the admin permission in the member center.

Comment: I'm the admin in member center.

Comment: Then you must be able to submit the apps. I am not sure what could the issue. Anyway, did u try to submit the app from Application Loader?

Answer (score -2):

You need to remove your user account from Xcode (Preferences > Accounts > Press -) and re-add it.

Comment: Users with technical role has even more limitations than users with Admin role.

Comment: take a look at my answer with the attached screen shot.